# DecimalDynamicDisplayFormat constant expression error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've a MVC Application that allows ADM user to change the decimal places of a decimal number dynamically.
I need to change the display format, so I wrote the following code:

```
    public ForecastProfitView(decimal? literPerUnit = null, int? _decimalPlaces = null)
    {
        LiterPerUnit = ((literPerUnit ?? 0) == 0) ? 1 : literPerUnit.Value;
        decimalPlaces = ((_decimalPlaces ?? 0) == 0) ? 2 : _decimalPlaces.Value;
    }

    private decimal LiterPerUnit { get; }
    private static int decimalPlaces { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Language.App_GlobalResources.AnalysisAndManagement), Name = "BottlingMaterialsCost")]
    [DecimalDynamicDisplayFormat(decimalPlaces)]
    public decimal BottlingMaterialsCost { get; set; }
```

When I set `[DecimalDynamicDisplayFormat(decimalPlaces)]`, it gives me an error, because I need a constant expression. Is there a way to workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You're limited to compile-time constants. Basically everything that can be a `const`.

I'd keep the format in a separate property as it is dynamic and do something like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BottlingMaterialsCost, bottlingMaterialsCostFormat)


@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BottlingMaterialsCost, "{0:0.00}")
```

**Update**. You can do something like this to compute your format:

```
var bottlingMaterialsCostFormat = ((_decimalPlaces ?? 0) == 0) ? "{0:00}" : "{0:" + new string('0', _decimalPlaces.Value) + "}";
```

Comment: can't figure it out

Comment: I updated my answer based on your `decimalPlaces` property. Main idea is to compute somehow that format.